# cte doesn't show parentid correctly

Tags: common-table-expression, sql-server-2012-express, localdb

db:

```
menuid  Name                          Url                                   Parentid  Value
1   Products                      node                                      NULL    0
2   Windows                       node                                      NULL    0
3   Store                         node                                      NULL    0
4   Download                      node                                      NULL    0
5   About                         node                                      NULL    0
6   Office                        node                                      1   0
7   Office 2003                   #                                         6   1
8   Office 2007                   #                                         6   1
9   Office 2010                   #                                         6   1
10  Mobile                        node                                      1   0
11  IPhone                        #                                         10  1
12  Htc                           #                                         10  1
13  XP                            #                                         2   1
14  Vista                         #                                         2   1
15  Windows 7                     #                                         2   1
16  Chrome                        node                                      4   0
```

query:

```
"WITH temp (menuid, name, url, parentid,value ) AS "+
                " (  SELECT  m.menuid, m.name, m.url, m.parentid,m.value " +
                " FROM menutable m "+
                " where m.menuid=1 " +

                " UNION ALL "+

                " SELECT mt.menuid, mt.name, mt.url, mt.parentid,mt.value " +
                " FROM  menutable mt INNER JOIN  temp t " +
                " on mt.parentid=t.menuid "+
                ") "+
                "SELECT menuid, name, url, COALESCE(parentid,0),value "+
                "FROM temp "
```

result:

```
MenuID  Name           ParentID Url  value
1   Products    0   node    0
6   Office          0   node    0
10  Mobile          0   node    0
11  IPhone          0   #   1
12  Htc         0   #   1
7   Office 2003 0   #   1
8   Office 2007 0   #   1
9   Office 2010 0   #   1
```

why parentid always 0?  i examine other examples but couldnt find the mistake. thanks...
.................................
................................
...............................
...............................

Comment: ***WHAT*** database system (and which version) is this for? Please also show us the relevant table structures!

Comment: microsoft local DB v11.